# How to use selectors with closest js

Tags: javascript, css

I have a simple task to make condition work by the next fired selector, but it does not work... Why?

```
  const closestImgWrap = target.closest("[class^='imageWrap'] > img")
```

Comment: What is the parent you want to target ??! the `[class^='imageWrap']` or the `img`..

Comment: body. But I do not want to target the parent node, I need to target current! @ZakariaAcharki

Comment: Isn't clear enough yet ... Add the structure of your HTML code

Comment: highly doubt you want the image since it can not have children.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki the question is about why this selector does not work, bot about the dom structure

Comment: @epascarello I what imageWrap, not img

Comment: so why is the `> img` in it? It is looking for a parent that is an image that is a direct child.

Comment: @MaxWolfen and how we could answer when we do not know if the selector is valid or not ??

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki you can simply help me jast said if my selector is worked or not in my question

Comment: If you want image wrap then this selector will never get you there

Comment: @epascarello because I need only nodes that contain img inside them

Comment: give us the html i've got an answer ready but need to know what you're selecting and where from

Comment: Well there you go, that is why it fails. If you said that, it would have been easy to answer and not 10 minutes of going back and forth.

Comment: @epascarello and what I can do in such case?

Comment: Well showing HTML would make it easier to give an answer....

Answer (score 2):

Your selector is looking for an image that is a child of another element. It is not looking for the wrapper element that contains an image.

If you want the image it would be:

```
const closestImgWrap = target.closest("[class^='imageWrap']").find("> img")
```

If you want the wrapper that you need to use has

```
const closestImgWrap = target.closest("[class^='imageWrap']:has('> img')")
```

Comment: this is a better answer use this